# Signrawtransaction is not working on bitcoin core V0.17.1

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, signrawtransaction

I am having trouble signing a transaction on bitcoin core since it appears signrawtransaction no longer works.

I get the following error message :

```
signrawtransaction is deprecated and will be fully removed in v0.18. To use signrawtransaction in v0.17, restart bitcoind with -deprecatedrpc=signrawtransaction.
Projects should transition to using signrawtransactionwithkey and signrawtransactionwithwallet before upgrading to v0.18 (code -32)
```

Any advice on what to do? tahnks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried any of the advice in the error message?

Comment: Hello! Yes I did, I clicked on bitcoind.exe, it launched the back window and then the window along with the file disappeared like 10 seconds after that and I can't find them anymore... Any idea on where it could be?

Comment: That's not how to start bitcoind. You need to run it from the command prompt. However, you really don't need to do that. Just change the command you are using.

Answer (score 5):

As the error message says, `signrawtransaction` is deprecated. Stop using it. Instead use `signrawtransactionwithwallet` (if the transaction you are signing uses keys from your wallet) or `signrawtransactionwithkey` (if you are specifying keys on the command line).

Comment: signrawtransactionwithwallet gives Method not found (code -32601)